# C# based lightweight application layer protocol - alternative to HTTP

Tags: c#, http, protocols, application-layer

I'm pretty new in C# and I'm developing C#(WPF) application with client/server architecture, and I'll need to communicate between two machines(only short JSONs, however a lot of them), and HTTP is too "heavy" with all it headers etc. Does exist any alternative to HTTP on application layer?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why not use WCF.

That way you can specify the type of communication method, named pipes, shared memory, http, tcp etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936243.aspx